# Push complex json record into a json variable using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I've been trying to push a complex json data record into a json variable. This is the code I tried to do so.

```
var marks=[];
var studentData="student1":[{
        "term1":[
            {"LifeSkills":[{"obtained":"17","grade":"A","gp":"5"}]},
            {"Work":[{"obtained":"13","grade":"A","gp":"5"}]}
              ]
         "term2":[
            {"LifeSkills":[{"obtained":"17","grade":"A","gp":"5"}]},
            {"Work":[{"obtained":"13","grade":"A","gp":"5"}]}
              ]
}];
marks.push(studentData);
```

But it doesn't push anything to the json array.Can anyone please help me to get rid of this.

Comment: first off, learn the basic syntax of JSON. it's not that difficult. You didn't even get the declaration of `studentData` right.

Comment: JSON syntax is incorrect. Correct it. Keep all data of json in braces.

Comment: FYI, you are working with JavaScript objects and arrays (and their literal representation). This has nothing to do with JSON at all. JSON is a *language-independent, textual data-exchange format*.

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thanks @MrUpsidown your link will be helpful to learn json format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r2zxyqp0/)  
here i corrected your json and checkout the demo

```
var studentData={
   "student1": [
       {
           "term1": [
               {
                   "LifeSkills": [
                       {
                           "obtained": "17",
                           "grade": "A",
                           "gp": "5"
                       }
                   ]
               },
               {
                   "Work": [
                       {
                           "obtained": "13",
                           "grade": "A",
                           "gp": "5"
                       }
                   ]
               }
           ],
           "term2": [
               {
                   "LifeSkills": [
                       {
                           "obtained": "17",
                           "grade": "A",
                           "gp": "5"
                       }
                   ]
               },
               {
                   "Work": [
                       {
                           "obtained": "13",
                           "grade": "A",
                           "gp": "5"
                       }
                   ]
               }
           ]
       }
   ]
}
var marks=[]; 
marks.push(studentData);
console.log(marks);
```

it successfully pushed into marks array

Comment: What you posted is a nested object/array, not JSON. Please don't refer to JavaScript object and array literals as "JSON".

Answer (score 2):

```
    var marks=[];
var studentData={"student1":[{
        "term1":[
            {"LifeSkills":[{"obtained":"17","grade":"A","gp":"5"}]},
            {"Work":[{"obtained":"13","grade":"A","gp":"5"}]}
              ],
         "term2":[
            {"LifeSkills":[{"obtained":"17","grade":"A","gp":"5"}]},
            {"Work":[{"obtained":"13","grade":"A","gp":"5"}]}
              ]
}]};
marks.push(studentData);
console.log(marks);
```

Here you go.

Answer (score 2):

You have make syntax error in the JSON object definition. Generally JSON object to be placed inside curly braces. And also comma is required between items. I have posted correct JSON definition of your studentData. Then you are able to push the JSON object to other array.

```
var studentdata={"student1":[{"term1":[
        {"LifeSkills":[{"obtained":"17","grade":"A","gp":"5"}]},
        {"Work":[{"obtained":"13","grade":"A","gp":"5"}]}
          ]}],"term2":[
        {"LifeSkills":[{"obtained":"17","grade":"A","gp":"5"}]},
        {"Work":[{"obtained":"13","grade":"A","gp":"5"}]}
          ]}
```

Regards,
Sunil Prabakar C

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: `Java != JavaScript`. The point of the article is that many people incorrectly refer to a *JavaScript object* as "JSON object".

Comment: able to use JSON in javascript too

Comment: I'm not denying that. All I am saying is that the "thing" you are referring to as "JSON object" is a **JavaScript object** (literal). It has nothing to do with JSON. Your example does **not** contain JSON. This is all explained in detail in the article I linked to. It's worth reading it.